# com.gradle.build-scan plugin was not found

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I recently started seeing below error in eclipse. seems like eclipse gradle plugin is not able to build the project however when i build from command prompt build is successful.

```
Plugin [id: 'com.gradle.build-scan', version: '2.1', artifact: 'com.gradle:build-scan-plugin:2.1'] was not found in any of the following sources:
```

The error is saying that plugin is missing. how do i install this plugin into gradle ?

Comment: If you get different results when running Gradle in Eclipse vs. on the command line, find out what you are doing differently. In your case the error says that Gradle can't find something somewhere (unfortunately the error message is truncated to tell where) which might be also due to different proxy settings.

Comment: I think something to do with corporate proxy

Comment: Does it work if you use in your Eclipse project your local Gradle installation: _Project > Properties: Gradle_?

Comment: it worked after importing the project in eclipse, probably during import I was able to download the required plugin. Previously i copied the workspace from other machine and every time i save the build,grade it gave me this error.